# hapi.js connected with mysql is not showing the value's on browser

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, hapi.js

i was trying to get the list of some datas from mysql using hapi.js. But  I'm getting this error

```
Error:  method did not return a value, a promise, or throw an error
```

but i can see those data's in my console.

> [ RowDataPacket { id: 1, code: 'test', description: 'bla', format: '12' },
>     RowDataPacket { id: 2, code: 'test2', description: 'test', format: '15' } ]

this is my handler code:

```
exports.getInfo = async (request, h) => {
    try {
            pool.query(`SELECT * FROM test`, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            return h.response(result);    
        });

    } catch (e) {
        if (e.response) {
            switch (e.response.status) {
                case 404: return Boom.notFound();
                default: return Boom.failedDependency();
            }
        } else {
            return Boom.failedDependency();
        }
    }
};
```

This is problem of promise, i guess mysql doesn't return any promise. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using async operator that means you can utilize the async/await approach in your code.

I assume that your `pool.query` method is returning a promise, so your code could be like this.

```
exports.getInfo = async (request, h) => {
    try {
        const result = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM test`);
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.response) {
            switch (e.response.status) {
                case 404:
                    return Boom.notFound();
                default:
                    return Boom.failedDependency();
            }
        } else {
            return Boom.failedDependency();
        }
    }
};
```

If not, then you can convert your `pool.query` method to a Promise.

```
const QueryResult = (query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(`SELECT * FROM test`, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);           
            return resolve(result)
        });
    })
}

exports.getInfo = async (request, h) => {
    try {
        const result = await QueryResult(`SELECT * FROM test`);
        return result;   
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.response) {
            switch (e.response.status) {
                case 404:
                    return Boom.notFound();
                default:
                    return Boom.failedDependency();
            }
        } else {
            return Boom.failedDependency();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, first one didn't work for me, got internal server error. 2nd one worked fine.

Comment: By the way this is just a sample application. In order to utilize your pool.query method fully you should adapt `QueryResult` accordingly to your query method or you should use promisified version of the query method. For example `QueryResult` doesn't accept additional parameters but I bet your query method would accept it to support prepared statements for sql. Just think about it and adapt.